# How to remove default onrowdelete confirm action (Are you sure you want to delete) ? in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How to remove default onrowdelete confirm action in Material-UI table (Are you sure you want to delete) ? in Reactjs

Comment: Are you sure you dont't turn it on somewhere. In default there is no confirm dialog provided at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify it in the localization props.
For example

```
 localization={{ body: { editRow: { deleteText: 'Customized Delete Message' } } 
 }}
```

Check the documentation for more localization props.

https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props

Comment: How does that **remove** it?

Comment: Ya,Thanks but , I am asking to remove the entire confirm action?